# SAPUI5 ODates, dates with GMT +1

Tags: sapui5

I have an issue where I'm providing a to date, then filtering some odata on that date....

```
  var effectiveTo = moment(oArgs.effectiveDateTo).format('YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00');

  new Filter("StartDate", FilterOperator.LE, moment(new Date(effectiveTo)).toDate())/
```

The problem is, if the date falls after the 26th March, +1 is added to the time in the StartDate, so the filter no longer returns the correct data.

Any ideas how I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when exchanging data with OData service values of DatTime type automatically converted to and from local browser timezone and also light saving periods. Probably you should pass Dates as strings? I've seen such a technique in standard SAP Fiori applications.

this is how SAP Leave Request app prepares dates before sending to the backend:

```
sStartDate = hcm.myleaverequest.utils.Formatters.DATE_YYYYMMdd(_oStartEndDates.startDate) + 'T00:00:00';
sEndDate = hcm.myleaverequest.utils.Formatters.DATE_YYYYMMdd(_oStartEndDates.endDate) + 'T00:00:00';
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Thank you. That's not the issue though, the issues is what's being returned from the SAP gateway, I'm passing in  var effectiveTo = moment(oArgs.effectiveDateTo).format('YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00'); but whats getting returned is adding +1

Comment: Probably you can change the service implementation at SAP side to make it return strings too?